# 16b Assembly - creating file with custom filename

Tags: assembly, dos, nasm, 16-bit

I am working on a program in 16b assembly that simply creates a file with a filename that I type myself in runtime and then closes it. The problem is - the file isn't created. Here is my code:

```
org 100h
mov ah, 9
mov dx, prompt
int 21h

mov ah, 0ah
mov dx, filename
int 21h

mov ah, 3ch
mov cx, 0000h
mov dx, filename+2
int 21h

mov word [filehandle], ax

mov bx, [filehandle]
mov ah, 3eh
int 21h


mov ah, 4ch
int 21h


prompt  db  "Filename:",10,13,"$"
filename db  10
         db  0
         times 11 db "$"
filehandle dw 0
```

As you can see I am using buffered input to read the filename. Unfortunately the file is not created. It works well if I hardcode the filename, like this:

```
...

mov ah, 3ch
mov dx, filename
int 21h

...

filename db "test.txt"
```

but that's not what I want to achieve. What is the reason behind this code not working? I am using NASM.

EDIT:
The problem is solved, @rkhb 's solution worked.

Comment: Try zero-terminating your filename.

Comment: @FrankKotler
you mean changing
    times 11 db "$"
to
    times 11 db 0
?

Comment: You have to place a zero byte after the 8.3 Filename. filename db 10, db 0, times 11 db "$", db  0, filehandle dw 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Int 21h / 3Ch` expects an ASCIIZ-string, i.e NULL terminated, but `Int 21h / 0Ah` gives you 0Dh (ENTER) as termination. So you must change 0Dh into 00h:

```
...
mov ah, 0ah
mov dx, filename
int 21h

movzx di, byte [filename+1]
add di, filename+2
mov byte [di], 0

mov ah, 3ch
mov cx, 0000h
mov dx, filename+2
int 21h
...
```